# When executing Firebase Functions from a Flutter app, the process stops

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I executed Firebase Functions in the following way

```dart
      result = await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(triggerName).call<void>();
```

When I run this process, the following error code is displayed, and the process stops

```
Error getting App Check token. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
```

However, I haven't implemented `App Check`. How can I resolve this error code and proceed with the subsequent processing?

Also, when checking the logs on the functions side, there are no errors or outputs.

By the way, during debugging, when confirming the operation with breakpoints, the process stops right after executing FirebaseFunctions. However, when I step through, the process continues without any issues...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're initializing your firebase-project

```
import 'package:firebase_app_check/firebase_app_check.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // Make sure you call this
  FirebaseAppCheck.instance // Only needed if you use App checks
      .installAppCheckProviderFactory(
          AppCheckProviderFactory(
              provider: SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory())
      );
  runApp(MyApp());

}
```

Comment: I have confirmed that it is initialized, but I haven't implemented `FirebaseAppCheck`, so I'm not initializing it.

Comment: By the way, during debugging, when confirming the operation with breakpoints, the process stops right after executing `FirebaseFunctions`. However, when I step through, the process continues without any issues...

Comment: Check that you're not being blocked by some other policy on your Firebase storage and that you have the access/permissions you need.

Comment: Could also be something else, hard to tell. Is the function actually triggering? Worst case change it to a HTTPS trigger and just call it like you would any endpoint